# Como fazer isso com ajax Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Imagine a seguinte situação:

Você está na página `index.php` e existe uma outra página chamada `formulario.php` com dois `input` e um `submit`.

Como faço pra enviar dados para a `formulario.php` e salvar o `submit` sem estar naquela pagina com jQuery?